# Invert tensor expression involving Levi-civita symbol

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, general-relativity

I have to prove that

$$
\omega_{\mu \nu} = \epsilon_{\mu \nu \lambda \kappa} \omega^\lambda u^\kappa
$$

given the relations:

$$
u_k u^k = -1
$$
$$
\omega_{\mu \nu} u^\nu = 0
$$
$$
\omega^\mu = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} \omega_{\alpha \beta} u_\nu
$$

I'm triying to solve this by multipliying at both sides by $u^{\nu}$ and then by $\epsilon_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}$ but i'm not sure how to handle correctly the resulting expression:

$$\omega^\mu u^{\nu} \epsilon_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}= \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} \epsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} \omega_{\alpha \beta} u_\nu u^{\nu}$$

I'm sure that I'm not doing this correctly because I'm mixing inner contractions. Some ideas about how this can be solved?

Comment: Remember that you can rename indices being summed over (they are dummy indices, like dummy variables of integration). Do this before substitution or multiplication so that newly introduced indices do not conflict with ones already present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if $\omega_{\alpha\beta}$ is antisymmetric (obviously, $\omega^\mu$ only contains info about the antisymmetric part, so that is the only part that can be recovered). Use the properties of the Levi-Civita symbols and generalised Kronecker delta symbols. Starting from:

$$\omega_{\mu \nu} = \epsilon_{\mu \nu \lambda \kappa} \omega^\lambda u^\kappa$$

Substitute in the definition of $\omega^\lambda$:
$$\omega_{\mu \nu} = \epsilon_{\mu \nu \lambda \kappa}\left( \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{\lambda \gamma \alpha \beta} \omega_{\alpha \beta} u_\gamma \right) u^\kappa$$

Group the Levi-Civita symbols, after a couple even permutations of their indices, and form the generalized Kronecker delta (it picks up a negative sign because of the Lorentzian signature):
$$\omega_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2}\omega_{\alpha \beta} u_\gamma u^\kappa \left( \epsilon_{\lambda \mu \nu \kappa} \epsilon^{\lambda \alpha \beta \gamma}  \right)$$

$$\omega_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2}\omega_{\alpha \beta} u_\gamma u^\kappa \left( -\delta_{\mu \nu \kappa}^{\alpha \beta \gamma}  \right)$$

Expand the delta symbol (this comes from Laplace's formula for evaluating a determinant):
$$\omega_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2}\omega_{\alpha \beta} u_\gamma u^\kappa  \left( -\delta^\gamma_\kappa \delta_{\mu \nu}^{\alpha \beta} +\delta^\gamma_\mu\delta^{\alpha\beta}_{\kappa\nu} +\delta^\gamma_\nu\delta^{\alpha\beta}_{\mu\kappa} \right)$$

$$\omega_{\mu \nu} = -\frac{1}{2}\omega_{\alpha \beta} u_\gamma u^\kappa \delta^\gamma_\kappa \delta_{\mu \nu}^{\alpha \beta} +\frac{1}{2}\omega_{\alpha \beta} u_\gamma u^\kappa\delta^\gamma_\mu\delta^{\alpha\beta}_{\kappa\nu} +\frac{1}{2}\omega_{\alpha \beta} u_\gamma u^\kappa\delta^\gamma_\nu\delta^{\alpha\beta}_{\mu\kappa} $$

The rank-2 delta changes the index of $u_\gamma$ and the rank-4 delta absorbs the $1/2$ and changes the indices of $\omega_{\alpha\beta}$ (and antisymmetrizes it, but it is already antisymmetric):
$$\omega_{\mu \nu} = -\omega_{\mu \nu} u_\kappa u^\kappa +\omega_{\kappa \nu} u_\mu u^\kappa +\omega_{\mu \kappa} u_\nu u^\kappa$$

Then equality is shown by $u_\kappa u^\kappa=-1$, $\omega_{\mu\nu}u^\nu=0$, and the antisymmetry of $\omega_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Perfect. Such a good explanation! Thank you so much for your beautiful response

Comment: Haven't you started with the thing you are trying to prove, rather than the definition? Surely you don't want the $\omega_{\mu\nu}=$ in the first bit?

Comment: @Chappers : I'm showing equality between the right hand side and left hand side. You are right, technically I should have started with the $\epsilon_{mnlk}\omega^l u^k$ on the left side as well, and left it there all the way through.

Comment: Yes, your approach is logically correct, but illogically written, so it looks circular.